# Modify Kibana Source Code for Pie Charts

Tags: elasticsearch, charts, kibana, kibana-4

We are Exploring possibilities to extend and modify Kibana. I am trying to customize the existing Pie Chart functionality by forking kibana and then adding some consoles and eventually add customizations in Pie_chart.js in src/cli/public/vislib/visualizations. When I do ./kibana from bin in my local branch  of kibana it gives me an error

```
/Users/schhatre/kibanSourceRepo/kibana/src/optimize/babel_options.js:4
let cloneDeep = require('lodash').cloneDeep;
    ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/schhatre/kibanSourceRepo/kibana/src/cli/index.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

**My forked Kibana is https://github.com/schhatre/kibana. I also removed 'Use Strict' since it was giving me Keyword 'Word' errors earlier when I run ./kibana**

Eventually I would like to start kibana by modifying kibana.yml with my IP and see my consoles and eventually move on to customize the Pie Charts.

I was successfully able to start Kibana and implement some plugins (Since plugins can be added in src/plugins and don't need Kibana Source code Changes) from downloaded zip but not from the github forked/cloned master branch's bin location.

Any help would be appreciated.I even went to an older 4.4 Version our company is on and tried to run ./kiban from /bin. Still no luck..

Swaraj

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your NodeJs version does not support ES2015 syntax. Make sure that you are using the proper version. To get the required NodeJs version:

```
cat .node-version
```

(your version is 4.4.4 on your repository)

Install this version with NVM (install NVM first if you don't have it):

```
nvm install v4.4.4
```

Use the version you just installed :

```
nvm use v4.4.4
```

Start Kibana:

```
npm start
```